# Need a function to convert the character to its name

Tags: windows, function, methods

I am wondering if there is some function in windows to convert a given char to its name.

cout << SomeFun('\t');
cout << SomeFun(' ');
cout << SomeFun(',');

Output is:
TAB
SPA
COMMA

Comment: I assume this relates to C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in either the Win32 API, the C++ standard library or the C standard library -- but you could easily [make one yourself](http://ideone.com/9VoCH) that uses a lookup table to return the result.